# APEX: Image links to data in table

Tags: image, hyperlink, oracle-apex

I have an image file in an html region in a page. I would like to create html links on the image that is linked to 2 specific fields in the database.

How can this be done?

Comment: You'll need to elaborate a bit. Is this about an image being in a blob? Is it about retrieving data (fetching column values)? Do you need to link to a page? Is it in a report (ie multi-row)? What version of apex are you on?

Comment: Hi Tom, I'm using apex 4.0. It's an GIF image (from WORKSPACE IMAGES).  I would like to create links on the image to retrieve data from a report. For example, name would be the link created and age,location would be related data related to the person's name that should be displayed or linked to the report

Comment: So essentially you need the link to refer you to a report page and provide 2 parameters (values for page items on the target page) to the report?

Comment: Yes, but when linked to the report page, it should only display values for that row of data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to construct a link, then you'll have to understand how the apex URL is constructed. You can read about that in the Oracle Docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21674/concept_url.htm#BEIJCIAG

Essentially, wrap the img tag in an anchor tag

```
<a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&SESSION_ID.::::P1_ITEM1,P1_ITEM2:Imavalue,imanothervalue">
   <img src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#some_img.png" />
</a>
```

Of course, if you want a query limited on your target page, you'll need to set up some page items on that page and include these in your where clause to limit the results. This should be basic, and if the concept is unfamiliar to you i suggest you take the 2-day developer guide for apex. It covers the basics, and you can take it from there: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21679/toc.htm